# Ubuntu installer on an Oracle VM virtual Box on windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu-12.04, virtual-machine

I am trying to install Ubuntu on windows using Oracle VM virtual Box from an ISO disk image.When I try to install, the installer gives a prompt that " The computer currently has no operating systems" I am wondering if this should have detected my windows operating system or is it just trying to detect Operating systems within the virtual Box.

The reason being it gives only two options to install
--Erase disk and install Ubuntu
-- Resize partition for Ubuntu

I do not want to erase all files on my windows operating system. Does anybody know what does the 'disk' in the discussion mean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer is looking for OS installations on the disk in the VM, not the host machine. You are perfectly safe selecting `Erase disk and install Ubuntu`, and in most situations in a VM, that is the correct choice.